# arabic word inserted in sql but with a warning sign

Tags: mysql, sql

i tried to insert arabic word in MySql and it got inserted and when i displayed it it was there
but there was a warning 3720

for context here is the table:

`create table SIGHTS ( S_no int not null PRIMARY KEY, S_name Nvarchar(30) not null);`

and here is the inserted value:
`insert into SIGHTS  values (1,(N'كهف الهكبة'));`

so? is it safe to ignore the warning or what should i do with it ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have used the default CHARACTER SET "utf8mb4" and the COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci when you create the database. for more information, check this [link out](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76529)

when you create the database using the default "*create*" statement, which is

```
CREATE DATABASE _dbase;
```

it will execute the following statement adding the default ***CHARACTER SET***

```
CREATE DATABASE _dbase CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

change the CHARACTER SET to "utf8" and the COLLATE to "utf8_general_ci" or "utf8_unicode_ci", you need to use the following statements :

```
CREATE DATABASE _dbase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

or

```
CREATE DATABASE _dbase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```